# Validates the presence of an option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form that I want to validate if an option has been selected. 
I do not want to accept the default starting option, "Please Select a Product"

I using this now and get a uninitialized contant error. I believe I am writing the syntax wrong.
Controller:

```
validates :product_name, :presence => { :unless => (product_name = "Please Select a Product")}
```

View:

```
        <span class="span5 pagination-right">
            <%= f.label "Product" %>
            <%= f.select :product_name, options_for_select([ ["Please Select a Product"] ]) %>
        </span>
```

How am I supposed to have the option written?
Thank you

The product_name is changed like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#ticket_product_name').html("<option>Please Select a Product</option>");
    $('#ticket_firmware_version_string').html("<option>Please Select a Firmware</option>");

    $('#category').change(function(){

        $('#ticket_product_name').html("<option>Please Select a Product</option>");
        $('#ticket_firmware_version_string').html("<option>Please Select a Firmware</option>");

        if ($('#category').val() == "blah")
        { 
            $('#ticket_product_name').append("<option>blah</option>");
            $('#ticket_product_name').append("<option>blah</option>");
        }
        else if ($('#category').val() == "another category")
        { 
            $('#ticket_product_name').append("<option>blah product</option>");
        }
```

until end of options, end script.

Comment: Please avoid editing the question so badly that an any answer given looks plain wrong. In this case, you could have just add your view code bellow.

Comment: The way you are doing your javascript filling process is not the best.  You options has not "value" attribute, it is not dynamic (for each new option of category, you'll need to update the code for the products). You should use AJAX to call the server with a category id, and respond with the list of corresponding products. Anyway, a workaround for you would be to catch the submit event of the form, test if the value of the Products select box is not "select a product", and then do your thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a placeholder for this select. In this case, I used a disabled option:

```
<% options = options_for_select(["Select an option", ["Product #1",1], ["Product #2",2]], disabled: "Select an option") %>

<%= f.select :product_name, options %>
```

Comment: I am using a script for the options with many if statements. Is there a way to use the controller to validate the presence without the default value? Maybe set a value to the default one? Or just not allow a string I specify?

Comment: Yes, some javascript: `$('form#your_form_id').on('submit',function(event){ if($('#ticket_product_name').val() == 'Select a product'){alert('choose a product!');return false;} else { return true; } })`

Comment: Why make a script, shouldn't the controller do the validation? this seems messy

Comment: @DDDD because you don't produce the option & select properly, if you want something not messy, first don't use javascript to fill the options.

Comment: I used javascript because the options change based on previous selections.

Comment: If you want ot do this way, then read my comment on your question: to summarize, you should listen on the Change event on the category select tag, when it changes you call the server with the selected category_id and the server returns the list of corresponding product.

Answer (score 2):

You should use include_blank from [the select helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select), like this:

```
<%= f.select :product_name, options_for_select([["opt1",1],["opt2",2]]), include_blank: true %>
```

and then, on model

```
validates :product_name, :presence => true
```

@MrYoshiji commented something truthful in my answer - if you are not allowing it to be blank, the easy way is simply not add a blank option in the select

Comment: So in the form you allow blank values to be submitted but then in the model you force the presence of the product? Pretty confusing

Comment: I had validates :product_name, presence: true    but I was trying that out.

Comment: Adding 100 options doesn't seem very efficient when they are already specified in my script.

Comment: @DDDD That is for sure. It was just an example. The issue seems how to validate a blank option and how to add it on the select, isn't it? Anyway, MrYoshiji solution is better.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use the `:prompt` option for your select helper (the documentation on this isn't quite straight forwward, but it's ok in this version of the same thing: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag). This allows you to define a helper string of text to encourage the user to select an option, but will submit a nil value back when the form is submitted.

```
<%= f.select :product_name, PRODUCT_NAME_OPTIONS, prompt: 'Select an option' %>
```

The next thing I'd recommend is... instead of validating presence of on the model, do a validates_inclusion_of. This way you can define the set of options in the model and then use that same set of options in the select helper, above, as well is in your validation. This way you know the form wasn't manipulated to include a different option and it actually keeps things a bit DRYer.

```
Product

PRODUCT_NAME_OPTIONS = {'opt 1' => 'opt1', 'opt 2' => 'opt2'}

validates_inclusion_of :product_name, :in => PRODUCT_NAME_OPTIONS.values, :message => 'choose from the available options'
```

Comment: prompt: 'Select an option' did not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making this too complicated, I just added a length validation since the default is much longer then the product names. Simple is best, however there should be a string validator option.

```
 validates :product_name, presence: true, length: {
maximum: 21,
too_long: ": Must select a product"
```

}